# stream reader over regex loop?

Tags: c#, regex

how I can apply stream reader over regex loop

please help 
i dont know

```
     string Value =pattern search;
        var match = Regex.Match(File.ReadAllText(patch ) , Value);  
    while (match.Success)
{

  doing regex code loop 
  }
```

please give me a hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Matches`.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(patch), Value);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    //do what you want with every match
}
```

Comment: thanks but this is a stream reader ?

Comment: What do you mean by stream reader?

Comment: i see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812538/regex-extremely-slow-on-large-documents , but i dont know how apply stream reader in a loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810693/is-there-a-fast-way-to-parse-through-a-large-file-with-regex